# <li> styling with css (chrome problems)

Tags: css, google-chrome

Hello I've got this weird problem with css.

I'm displaying an unordered list

```
  <ul>
   <li>
    <div class='align-left'>
     PMI
    </div>
    <div class='align-right'>
     <img src="/img/delete_icon2.png" id='19' class="elim" name="19">
    </div>
   </li>
   <li>
    <div class='align-left'>
     GRANDS COMPTES
    </div>
    <div class='align-right'>
     <img src="/img/delete_icon2.png" id='21' class="elim" name="21">
    </div>
   </li>
   <li>
    <div class='align-left'>
     associations
    </div>
    <div class='align-right'>
     <img src="/img/delete_icon2.png" id='22' class="elim" name="22">
    </div>
   </li>
   <li>
    <div class='align-left'>
     PME
    </div>
    <div class='align-right'>
     <img src="/img/delete_icon2.png" id='25' class="elim" name="25">
    </div>
   </li>
   <li>
    <div class='align-left'>
     ecoles privees
    </div>
    <div class='align-right'>
     <img src="/img/delete_icon2.png" id='28' class="elim" name="28">
    </div>
   </li>
   <li>
    <div class='align-left'>
     organisme
    </div>
    <div class='align-right'>
     <img src="/img/delete_icon2.png" id='32' class="elim" name="32">
    </div>
   </li>
   <li>
    <div class='align-left'>
     test
    </div>
    <div class='align-right'>
     <img src="/img/delete_icon2.png" id='34' class="elim" name="34">
    </div>
   </li>
  </ul>
```

now this is accompanied by these css rules:

```
.align-right{
float: right;
}
.align-left{
float: left;
}
```

On chrome, the bullet point from the list is actually UNDER the text for the bullet point.

Why did I do this, I want the images to be aligned from top down.

here are screenshots of the [problem](http://imgur.com/vMQIvl&HrpAQ)

thanks in advance.

Comment: formating problems, trying to fix, one sec

Comment: Hmm, now I know an image hosting service I *won't* use.

Comment: two minutes is more than one sec. Let me help. ;-)

Comment: Robert Harvey ???? what is wrong with imgur?

Comment: You should post your HTML by indenting it with four spaces.  (click the `{}` button)

Comment: @cromestant: want to post HTML to Stack Overflow? [Here's how.](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: You could just use the `{}` button to indent your code 4 spaces. That will automatically format it as code. (That's what I actually did before you removed the lot.) :)

Comment: can you send this example codes via jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: thanks for the formatting, I had used the {} and it had not worked.

Comment: I will completely offend the purists, which is why this is a comment and not an answer, but if you're really struggling with getting the unordered list to look the way you want, *just put it into a table.* You'll get complete, localized control over the look and feel.

Comment: nope, no tables this is the reason I'm trying to do this, trying layouts without tables.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

the code you provided won't cause this problem.

Depending on what you want to do, adding

`ul { list-style-type:none; }`

or

`ul li { padding-left:40px; }`

may achieve desired effect.

*edit*

try adding `overflow:hidden;` to the `li` elements

I'd also personally do it like this:

```
li { 
    background:url(/img/delete_icon2.png) no-repeat center right; 
    padding-right:25px; /*might need to adjust */
}

    <ul>
        <li>PMI</li>
        <li>Bla bla</li>
    </ul>
```

no need to over-complicate things.

If you want the DIVS clickable you can just do

`<li><a href="delete.php">PMI</a></li>`

and CSS:

`li a { display:block; width:xxx; height:xxx; }`

as required.

Comment: the padding fixes half of the bullet points, but nothing complete yet.

Comment: partial solution, that works, will investigate the rest. this hides the bullet points, but that is not intended thing. willbe back tomorow, work day is over thanks for hte help marked as solved because it is in part solved

Comment: If you want the bullet points you can have them, but you need to provide all the CSS + exactly what you intend. Ideally use jsfiddle.net or similar for best results.

Comment: this fixed my problem. I was getting some weird top padding I couldn't explain and it was because the ul had a list-style.

Answer (score 3):

Try playing with the `list-style-position` property. Options are `inside` and `outside`.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I misunderstood the question. I thought you were wanting to realign the dots to the right side.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it seems that you do not have exact control over the position of the default bullet point.

For me the following was working in Firefox and in IE, but in Chrome it is positioned inside the text:

```
<ul style="list-style-position: outside; margin:0; padding:0;">
   <li />
   <li />
</ul>
```

I needed to set margins and paddings for both the list and the list items to get the bullet point(disk) outside the text

```
<ul style="list-style-position: outside; margin:10px; padding:10px;">
   <li style="padding: 10px 0 0 3px; margin-bottom: 8px;" />
   <li style="padding: 10px 0 0 3px; margin-bottom: 8px;" />
</ul>
```

The strange part is, that if I set those bottom margins to anything less than 7 pixel, the bullets jump inside. 8px is the smallest working value, although there is lots of space around and between the elements (they move closer to each other fluently, only the bullet points start to jump).